# Azure DevOps Permission- ByPass rules on work item for REST API - throws error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am using a service account (user account), and the service account has read and write access to the projects under the organization. I have generated a PAT using this service account and using it in the API which calls the DevOps Rest API.

I have set read-only rules to a couple of fields in DevOps, I am bypassing the rule while calling the DevOps API (bypass:true) but it throws this error "TF401322: You don't have bypass rules permission. Please contact collection admin".

My question is : how do I set ByPass rules on work items to "Allow" for this service account ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way: add your service account to Project Administrators :). You can create separate group, add your service account to it and Allow Bypass for this group. Here is permission:

[image]

Additional links:

1. ["Bypass rules on work item updates" is not working as expected](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/331221/bypass-rules-on-work-item-updates-is-not-working-a.html)
2. [Azure DevOps: create a comment on behalf of another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964647/azure-devops-create-a-comment-on-behalf-of-another-user)