# Create VssCredentials based on the currently authenticated user

Tags: c#, azure-devops, active-directory, adal, workitem

I'm authenticating users to my WebAPI app from an Angular app using ADAL + Windows Azure Active Directory as follows:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"]
            },
        });
}
```

This is working without issue.

I have some code for modifying work items in Azure DevOps:

```
 Uri baseVsoUri = new Uri("https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
 VssCredentials creds = new VssBasicCredential("", azureDevOpsPersonalAccessToken);
 VssConnection conn = new VssConnection(baseVsoUri, creds);

 ...

 await conn.UpdateWorkItemAsync(jsonPatchOperations, 1);
```

The problem I'm facing is because my Personal Access Token is being used to authenticate with Azure DevOps, I am listed as having updated the WorkItem.

Is it possible to create a `VssCredentials` object for the user currently authenticated with the WebAPI?

**Edit**

I tried the code suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964647/azure-devops-create-a-comment-on-behalf-of-another-user) question to set the `ChangedBy` property myself but I don't have the required permission:

`You don't have bypass rules permission. Please contact your collection administrator to grant this permission for enabling this action.`

Comment: you can update the work item behalf another user, check here the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964647/azure-devops-create-a-comment-on-behalf-of-another-user

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Unfortunately I don't have permission to use the `bypassRules` property

Answer (score -1):

You can check out this [example project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample) to use ADAL to authenticate a user via an interactive prompt and call rest api.

You can also check out this document [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) to generate an access token for the users and then use the token to call rest api,

> Authenticate your web app users for REST API access, so your app doesn't continue to ask for usernames and passwords. Azure DevOps Services uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize your app for a user and generate an access token. Use this token when you call the REST APIs from your app.

Here is the [example project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample) you can check out.

For more examples see [Choosing the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops).